# How to create a function within function

Tags: r, function, r-mice

I have a problem in creating my function to impute my generated missing values. I have a generating data function, generating missing values function and imputing missing values function. But how can I combine them into one function?

```
# generate data
data <- function (n,alpha,kappa,miu){
    X = rvm(n,alpha,kappa)
    delta = rvm(n, 0, kappa)
    epsilon = rvm(n, 0, kappa)
    x = (X + delta)%%(2*pi)
    Y = (alpha + X)%%(2*pi)
    y = (Y + epsilon)%%(2*pi)
    sample = cbind(x,y)
    return(sample)
    }

#generate missing values
misVal <- ampute(data=data(10,0.7854,5,0),prop=0.25,bycases=FALSE)

#impute missing values
impData <- mice(misVal,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)
summary(impData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine all three functions into one large custom function...

```
nameYourFunction <- function(n,alpha,kappa,miu){

X = rvm(n,alpha,kappa)

delta = rvm(n, 0, kappa)

epsilon = rvm(n, 0, kappa)

x = (X + delta)%%(2*pi)

Y = (alpha + X)%%(2*pi)

y = (Y + epsilon)%%(2*pi)

sample = cbind(x,y)

#generate missing values

misVal <- ampute(data=sample,prop=0.25,bycases=FALSE)

#impute missing values

impData <- mice(misVal,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)

return(impData)
}
```

Then to run...

```
final_data <- nameYourFunction(n = 10, alpha = 0.7854, kappa = 5, miu = 0)
summary(final_data)
```

Obviously you may want to rename the function based on your own preferences.
If you wanted something more flexible, like to be able to easily supply arguments for the other function called within `nameYourFunction`, then you would add them to the list of arguments provided in the first line of code. So it might end up looking more like...

`nameYourFunction <- function(n,alpha,kappa,miu,prop,m,maxit,meth,seed){...}`
Then supplying those values to the function call like...

`final_data <- nameYourFunction(n = 10, alpha = 0.7854, kappa = 5, miu = 0, prop = 0.25, m = 5, maxit = 50, meth = 'pmm', seed = 500)`

And removing the hard coded values from within the custom function. I would probably recommend against this though as that is a lot of arguments to keep track of!

Comment: Hi, tq for your answer but I got an error stated that "Data should be a matrix or data frame". How can I correct them? @EChisholm

Comment: Sorry i would need more info to help you with this.